# CSS selector scoping

Tags: html, css, web, scope

Let's assume we have this code:

```
<section id="block">
  <p>Some Text</p>
  <p class="test">Some Text With Class 'test'</p>
  <p>Some More Text</p>
</section>

<p>Some Text</p>
<p class="test">Some Text With Class 'test'</p>
<p>Some More Text</p>
```

So I want to style `<p>` and `<p class="test">` inside `<section id="block">` **only**.

---

This CSS can be used to do so:

```
#id p {
  ...
}

#id .test {
  ...
}
```

However I think it is a bit distracting in case of long ids such as `#my-very-long-id` for example.

---

Another way to achieve this is to use `<style scoped></style>` tags.

But it is not really convenient to have CSS code in HTML and furthermore it is mostly not supported by most browsers (as caniuse.com says).

---

**My question**: is there a way to declare some kind of selector scoping **inside** CSS?

It would be cool to have something like this:

```
@scope(#id) {
  p {
    /* ... */
  }

  .test {
    /* ... */
  }
}
```

Comment: your are doing the same in first demo, so the idea of scope, is done by css default. I think is not necessary, and CSS is not a language programing, that is important to undertand. You can find by sass or less what you expected to do

Comment: Look into [SCSS](http://sass-lang.com/guide).

Comment: Thank you. It actually what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go for http://sass-lang.com/guide
This might help you !

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
#id {
  p {
    /* ... */
  }

  .test {
    /* ... */
  }
}
```

only with LESS or SASS, not with css.

Why don't you do

```
#id > p{ your style }
```

so every p inside that id will take that style. And for more aditional style for class .test , you can declare it separated.